# Unable to scroll down and view text because of css3 hight vh property

Tags: html, css

In the responsive one page site- The 'About Us' tab has more text than the other tabs- and the overflowed text is not seen.

The site uses css3, it uses the vh property, for making the site responsive- and it works, but as a result I can't scroll down to view large text tab.

I have added an example for you to try: [Code example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGvaEQ) (there's also a share link which you can download the content)
Notice only the 'About us' tab has "too much" text, the other tabs works 
fine.
I would like the be able to see the whole text at the 'About Us' tab.

html (navbar):

```
<nav class="nav nav--active">
    <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="" class="nav__link"> <div class="nav__thumb color1" data-letter="a"></div>
            <p class="nav__label">
                About
            </p> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="" class="nav__link"> <div class="nav__thumb color2" data-letter="p"></div>
            <p class="nav__label">
                Products
            </p> </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

content:

```
<div class="page">
    <section class="section section--active color1" data-letter="a">
        <article class="section__wrapper">
            <h1 class="section__title">About us</h1>
            <p>
                John Doe is ... long text
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
    ...
</div>
```

css3:

```
.page{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

To sum it up:
The css3 height vh property prevent the page from scrolling down to view the text. How to fix that?

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden` from the section class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the measurement unit (vh). Your text is just too long to fit in the page and you specified `overflow: hidden;` on the section tag, so it won't allow a scroll bar to see all of the text. Simply, remove `overflow: hidden;` from your "section class" as well as your "page" class. So your fixed preprocessed CSS section would look like this:

```
.section
    will-change transform
    position absolute
    width 100%
    top 0
    left 0
    height 100vh
    align().burger__patty
          transform rotate(45deg)
        &:before
          transform rotate(-90deg) translate(-9px, 0)
        &:after
          opacity 0
          transform scaleX(0)


          text-align center
          background white
          transform translateX(100%)
          easeout(.7s)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I removed the overflow: hidden;
but still- I can't read the 'about us' tab text.
Notice the 'about us' tab text last line is:
"likes to get out with his friends."
As seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVOrJe

Comment: @Roko if you remove the height from the `.section` your problem is solved but arises a new one. Removing the height (or making it auto) wraps the height of the content. But now on the smaller content tabs, you have empty space. This should be able to be fixed by making the other sections `display: none;` while they are not visible.